# firebase cloud messaging gives A bad HTTP response code (404) after clicking on 'allow' and adding service worker manually doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a React app and trying to add FCM to the project. First I tested FCM on a simple (non-React) project with a simple index.html and everything worked fine but now adding it to the React app is a bit problematic for me.

So here is the issue:

I created a simple `initializeFirebase` function and made it to be called at the `index.js` of the app. Here is the function:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
const firebaseConfig = {
     ... // FCM configs
  };
  
  export const initializeFirebase = () => {

    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
       return messaging.getToken();
    }).then(function(token) {
       console.log(token);
    }).catch(function() {
       console.log('Access Denied!');
    });
```

So this is expected to ask user for permission and then log the `token`. But after it asks and I click allow, I get this error on console.
`A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.` And it goes into catch block.

As I searched it was mentioned to set service worker manually like this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then((registration) => {        
      // Here ask for permission and get the token
    });
```

But beside the `A bad HTTP ...` I also get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8081/') with script ('http://localhost:8081/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.`

I saw some people told that SW file doesn't get loaded or found. I tried everything in this matter. I put the file in root directory at first and it didn't for with/without setting SW manually. I put it beside the file that had `initializeFirebase` and passed it like `'./firebase-messaging-sw.js'`, still no change. I just wanna make it work it doesn't matter if I set service worker manually or just let firebase find the file itself.

NOTE: The SW files doesn't get loaded when I set: `http://localhost:8081/firebase-messaging-sw.js`
or `http://localhost:8081/src/firebase-messaging/firebase-messaging-sw.js` in broswer. I don't know this is important or not.

Here is also the content of my `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-messaging.js');

const firebaseConfig = {
     ... // FCM configs
  };
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload){
  const notif = JSON.parse(payload.data.notification);
  return self.registration.showNotification(notif.title, {...notif});
});
```

I would absolutely appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Well it was quite silly mistake of mine, and as I expected it was the problem of not loading the sw file correctly. The path was not right.

If you're here and dealing with similar issue, make sure to put your sw file in the public folder so `http://localhost:8081/firebase-messaging-sw.js` would load in your browser and then other parts would be fine.

I found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sazzadsazib/how-to-send-notification-to-react-app-using-firebase-f257d4bdca28) quite helpful for the whole process of adding FCM to your React app. Do its instruction step by step and you're good to go.